# Installing A TGZ FILE

Tags: installation

I have downloaded a .tgz file which when extracted gives me two files called "EULA.txt" and "install.pl" but I have no idea what to do and how to install them, can anyone help please

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal, navigate to your folder and then try using this command:

```bash
./install.pl
```

if the perl script does not contain a path to the perl executable, you'll have to run it manually as a perl script:

```bash
perl install.pl
```

If none of above works, try setting executable permition to the file and try again.

```bash
chmod +x install.pl
```

Comment: How do I open a terminal

Comment: press Crtl+Alt+T, or open the dash and type "terminal"

Comment: If you've never used a terminal, you can check [this video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xE_WzWR2IwY).

Comment: how do I then navigate to find my file, sorry this is the first time I have ever used ubuntu I have only ever used windows

Comment: Check the video I posted, you can go to a directory typing `cd`, to list all files in a directory, use `ls`, keep going your folders until you find the place you extracted your files.

Comment: ive found the extracted files and have used the commands you suggested but it doesnt seem to install anything it just opens a text file and i have no idea where to go from here

Comment: Try posting a screenshot of what you've done as an edit to your question.

Comment: this is what I get

Comment: /home/paulm/Pictures/Screenshot from 2012-11-03 16:34:32.png

Comment: This is the path to your screenshot. Try uploading it to a photohosting service like www.imgur.com (Drag and Drop it onto the site to upload it). Then post the link here.

Comment: [IMG]http://i.imgur.com/2S8HX.png[/IMG]

Comment: This a screenshot of where I get to